# How to call an external API webservice from Python in Amazon Lambda?

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am pretty new to AWS Lambda i have a python code which has a post method for making an external API call,

```
import requests
import json
url = "http://sample/project"
headers = {
   'content-type': "application/json" 
    }
r = request.post(url,headers=headers)
```

I tried putting it into a AWS Lamda call i tried like this below but it didn't get worked out

```
import requests
    import json
    url = "http://sample/project"
    headers = {
       'content-type': "application/json" 
        }

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers)
    return response
```

But i am not getting in any response if i am running from local machine i am getting the output.Please help me how can i make a post call from AWS Lamda

Comment: Increase the configured Lambda function timeout (from 3 second default), then add some print statements into your code (viewable in CloudWatch Logs after your function is invoked) to help debug the problem.

Comment: Your Lambda function also must have access to the Internet, so if it's in a VPC, that means the Lambda function must be associated with private (not public) subnets, and those subnets must have their default route pointing to a NAT device.